# How to get result of a group by where records should both exist in a match and not exists in another match

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, sql-server-2017

**Question:**

I need to make a SELECT query that returns `shift_id` where
`day_of_week` is `IN (0,1,2,3,4)` and `NOT IN (5,6)`,
as in:

*"Find shift where shift days are Sunday through Thursday (and no records exist for Friday-Saturday)"*

**DB Structure:**

Table `shifts`:

```
shift_id - int, primary key
...      - other columns
```

Table `shift_days`:

```
shift_day_id - int, primary key
shift_id     - int, foreign key to shifts table
day_of_week  - int, where 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday,..., 6 - Saturday
...          - more columns
```

Ex.

- If shift is Monday - Friday, then `shift_days` only has 5 records with `day_of_week` from 1 to 5
- If shift is Sunday - Thursday, then `shift_days` only has 5 records with `day_of_week` from 0 to 4

DB Fiddles:

- [DB Fiddle (original posted)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=688c4635da535320842d0a34ba6d46a7)
- [DB Fiddle (live-updated with answers)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=25cb735af5a41d77e8c6f82dcc25fcb8)

**P.S.**
I was able to come up with this query:

```
SELECT shift_id
FROM (
    SELECT shift_id, STRING_AGG(day_of_week, ',') AS 'days_of_week'
    FROM shift_days
    GROUP BY shift_id
) AS sdw
WHERE sdw.days_of_week = '0,1,2,3,4'
```

but I don't know how to guarantee order to be ascending as '0,1,2,3,4' and I would like to see if there is an alternative to using STRING_AGG in case I want to use for different SQL dialects.

**P.P.S.**

Again the emphasis is that any shift that matches day_of_week (5,6) is a wrong match, since I want to exclude these records.
AND I want to include (0,1,2,3,4) records, which must have all 0-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Can try with below query:

**If you want all shifts not having `day_of_week 5,6`**

```
SELECT DISTINCT shift_id
FROM shift_days S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shift_days T WHERE T.shift_id=S.shift_id AND 
T.day_of_week in (5, 6))
```

**If you want all shifts having `day_of_week 0,1,2,3,4`**

```
SELECT  shift_id FROM shift_days S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shift_days T WHERE T.shift_id=S.shift_id AND 
T.day_of_week in (5, 6))
and day_of_week in (0,1,2,3,4)
group by shift_id having count(1)=5
```

**For reference [click here for demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5f974f89176a091d4b77c32e596ddfd5)**

Comment: This is a good start, but how do I combine it with "Must be in (0,1,2,3,4)"

Comment: I think the modified answer is exactly what I need, thank you!

As I understand I can replace COUNT(1) with COUNT(shift_id)?

So by first NOT matching (5,6), the group by will return ones that match "day_of_week in", and HAVING COUNT matches # of records in that group "day_of_week in". Plus I can loosely match something like IN (0,1,2,3,4) .... HAVING COUNT (shift_id) > 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
group by shift_id
having
    count(case when day_of_week in (5, 6) then 1 end) = 0
    and count(distinct day_of_week) = 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very similar to Somendra Kanaujia's answer and it gives me more insights on how to use group by ... having and manipulating group results. Big kudos to you!